# In what format is this time: 568399396

Tags: date, format

in my current project I need to work with data from a certain loger. Unfortunately, I encountered a problem of  coding the date of this loger. I believed that it is a timestamp date format but it is not. Can you tell me in what  format is this datum
Real date:

```
04-Jan-2018 16:43:16
```

Date format:

```
568399396
```

Comment: As a UNIX timestamp, `568399396` corresponds to `01/05/1988 @ 4:43pm (UTC)`.

Answer (score 0):

That date-time format is called epoch, where the date is stored as an integer. It is the number of seconds/milliseconds after 1st January 1970, 00:00:00. This is how all the computers/devices store the date/time internally.

You can use n number of libraries to convert an epoch to date/time etc.

You can read more about epoch here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

P.s.: Are you sure that you're getting this number for 4th Jan 2018? The epoch of 04-Jan-2018 16:43:16 will be 1515064396000(in ms)